# Does |x-c| and $\delta$ refer to one same thing: the distance between c and x in the x-axis, well why |x-c|<$\delta$?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

The way i understand $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ proof is this:
Given a  $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) = L $ suppose we have a $\epsilon > 0$ (a change for L over the y-axis) for every $\epsilon$>0 there gonna be a $\delta$>0 (again a change for c in the x-axis), so this is it $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ is small change of the values L and c.
But the definition -$\delta$<x-c<$\delta$  <=> |x-c|<$\delta$, says something else i think, it says the change over the x-axis is the distance |x-c| which means $\delta$ is definitely not the change , because if it's the case it would be |x-c| = $\delta$, so what is exactly is delta,  this expression-$\delta$<x-c<$\delta$ is saying for me that $\delta$ is the interval in which the change is happening , can you clarify please.

Comment: $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ both represent **ranges** of change in the appropriate axis. We don’t get $|f(x)-L|=\epsilon,$ either, we get $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon.$

Comment: thanks for reaching out ? $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ are the intervals in which the change is happening and |x-c| is the change itself , am i right?

Comment: $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ are not the ranges, they just decide the ranges. $c-\delta<x<c+\delta$ and $L-\epsilon<f(x)<L+\epsilon$ are the ranges. $|x-c|<\delta$ is just a convenient way to write that range of values for $x.$ You can call it “change” if you like, but it is not the key (and “change,” to me would imply direction.) More typically we’d call $|x-c|$ the distance, or maybe the difference.

Comment: What you're saying is that |x-c| is the distance however $\delta$ is what's represent the range of that distance, well is that mean that we need a range for the limit to exist, other ways i don't see the necessity for a range to be , i think we can represent it just with the distance , how far we're from c, a range's definition is the set of possible outputs , is $\delta$ the possible outputs of $\epsilon$ and vice versa, is that why we need a range to announce the dependency of $\epsilon$ over $\delta$ and vice versa? can you clarify why we need range for a limit ?

Comment: Given an $\epsilon$ there will be lots of $\delta$s that work. In fact, if $\delta_0$ works, then any other $\delta$ with $0<\delta_0<\delta$ works. We only need that given an $\epsilon$ there is one $\delta,$ but if there is one $\delta$ there are infinitely many.

Comment: Why we need a range for a limit? If $f(x)=x(1-x)$ then $f(1)=0.$ That is not the reason that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0.$ The values of $f(x)$ for $x>1/2$  Don’t affect the limit. Neither do the values of $x>10^{-100}.$  For the limit as $x\to 0,$ we only care about the values of $x$ near $0.$ “Near zero” is best described as “some range around $0.$” Usually, unless $f$ is constant near $c,$ as you pick smaller $\epsilon$ you require smaller $\delta.$

Comment: You don’t just need one or two $x$ with $0<|x-c|<\delta$ to have the property that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon,$ you need all such $x.$

Comment: In any event, despite much effort, I’m having a hard time making out your confusion. This usually means you are making an assumption that you haven’t enunciated. It may be a wrong interpretation which seems very obvious to you. My experience is that, as you get used to $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs, they start making more sense. You see why the definition “works” by using it in examples. The definition alone is confusing at first.

Answer (score 3):

$\delta$ and $\epsilon$ both represent **ranges** of change in the appropriate axis. We don’t get $|f(x)-L|=\epsilon,$ either, we get $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon.$

So we are saying that we can restrict the range of $f(x)$ to $L-\epsilon<f(x)<L+\epsilon$ if we restrict the range of $x$ to $c-\delta<x<c+\delta$ and $x\neq c.$

It turns out the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition is equivalent to:

> **Equivalent definition of** $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=L:$

> For any real $y_1,y_2$ with $y_1<L<y_2$ there exists a pair of reals $x_1,x_2$ With $x_1<c<x_2$ such that for $x_1<x<x_2$ (and $x\neq c$), we have $y_1<f(x)<y_2.$

This is saying, “For any range around $L,$ there is a range around $c$ where, if $x$ is in the range around $c,$ but $x\neq c,$ then $f(x)$ is in the range around $L.$”

$\epsilon-\delta$ is useful because “all ranges” is a bit much to handle. $\epsilon-\delta$ becomes something we can handle computationally.